# What difference does it make change the order which you import modules on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So i was trying to learn the basics of creating GUI's with Tkinter, and i found this code in a tutorial:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):                
        Frame.__init__(self, master)                
        self.master = master                
        self.init_window()    

    def init_window(self):        
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label="Show Img", command=self.showImg)
        edit.add_command(label="Show Text", command=self.showTxt)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)

    def showImg(self):
        load = Image.open("chat-min.png")        
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)

    def showTxt(self):
        text = Label(self, text="Maximum effort!")
        text.pack()

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This code just creates a window, with a cascade menu and two options: File that has Exit that close the window; Edit that has Show Img and Show Text, that display a image and a text respectively.

And if i switch the two lines where im importing tkinter, and ImageTk, Image, like this:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *
```

I get an error saying that: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open', when i click on Show Img, everything else works. Could anyone explain to me why this happens? Or what's wrong?

Comment: Order only matters if there is a clash, with the last import winning (redefining), e.g. `tkinter.Image` redefines `PIL.Image` because it comes after. You can avoid this by keeping the `tkinter` import in a namespace, e.g. `import tkinter as tk` and then `tk.XXX` for any call in that module. It is generally best to avoid `*` all imports.

Comment: I would suggest you post this as an answer since this is already a complete explanation of his 'what's wrong' question.

Comment: @AChampion Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order only matters if there is a clash, with the last import winning (redefining), e.g. `tkinter.Image` redefines `PIL.Image` because it comes *after*. You can avoid this by keeping the [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) import in a namespace, e.g. `import tkinter as tk` and then `tk.XXX` for any call in that module. It is generally best to avoid `*` all imports.

---

The answer is provided by the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877086/what-difference-does-it-make-change-the-order-which-you-import-modules-on-python#comment84758237_48877086).